# Linker error: "undefined reference to" only in particular function, of the same file

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I have a strange linker (GCC AVR) problem:

These are the declarations of the functions to call:

```
void* MEMPOOL_API_CALL MemPool_Memory_Alloc_Func(cyg_uint32);
void* MEMPOOL_API_CALL MemPool_Memory_ReAlloc_Func(void*, cyg_uint32);
```

I have these two functions, they are right after each other in the same file:

Header file:

```
void *memAllocate(size_t wantedSize);
void *memReallocate(void *mem, size_t wantedSize);
```

C file:

```
void *memAllocate(size_t wantedSize)
{
    void* ptr = MemPool_Memory_Alloc_Func(wantedSize); 
    if (!ptr) {
        // OOM
        LOG_E(SYSTEM, "Out of memory");
        ENABLE_ARMING_FLAG(ARMING_DISABLED_OOM);
    }
    return ptr;
}

void *memReallocate(void* mem, size_t wantedSize)
{
    void* ptr = MemPool_Memory_ReAlloc_Func(mem, wantedSize);
    if (!ptr) {
        // OOM
        LOG_E(SYSTEM, "Out of memory");
        ENABLE_ARMING_FLAG(ARMING_DISABLED_OOM);
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

`MemPool_Memory_Alloc_Func()` in `memAllocate()` throws an "undefined reference to" error, `MemPool_Memory_ReAlloc_Func()` in `memReallocate()` does not.
But when I test `MemPool_Memory_Alloc_Func()` and `MemPool_Memory_ReAlloc_Func()` and swap them, suddenly `MemPool_Memory_ReAlloc_Func()` throws the error?

Comment: "But when I test `MemPool_Memory_Alloc_Func()` and `MemPool_Memory_ReAlloc_Func()` and swap them, suddenly `MemPool_Memory_ReAlloc_Func()` throws the error?" I'm not crystal clear what this means. But, presumably the binary code for these `MemPool_Memory_` functions live in a library somewhere that you need to link in. Are you including that? Furthermore, the _order_ in which you link things matters. It might be helpful to identify the library with that function code and what you're entering to build.

Comment: Looks to me like the rest of your code might never actually call `memReallocate` - so, that code is eliminated and any functions that would be called from within it are never actually referenced. And, if they're not referenced, there'll be no *undefined* reference.

Comment: ... which, ultimately, suggests that your linkage doesn't actually include *either* of the two `MemPool_...` functions.